# How can I make sure search engines can see the content on my "single page" Backbone.js site?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo

So I have to build a website ideally based on Backbone.js. This website will be a sort of complex gallery, lets say hosted at **www.example.com**,  and I need every content which I open from this gallery to be searchable on google, lets say for example **www.example.com/content/contentIDNumber**. So I use the router class to define this route and handle page change as you normally would with backbone. All fine til here.

The gallery will be filled with an infinite list of dynamically loaded content. The content is created via a custom CMS, so we won't really be able to predict the list of pages, or create a sitemap in advance or something like that.

This said, I know I can easily change title and description of the html container dynamically when I visit that new page, but will this be enough for the site to show up on google? My client hasn't requested that we actually do proper SEO, they just want to know that specific pages will show up on google if searched. So if the title of the **www.example.com/content/contentIDNumber** page is "chihuahua specialties" they just want to know that searching for **example.com chihuahua specialties** they'll find it on google.

Sorry if I didn't exaplain myself too well, hope someone can help!
Please ask if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Turn of javascript an try to reach the pages by following links from the startpage. If this is possible then it is most likely that it will be in the index of the search engine. (But there is a huge list of points you need to look at: double content, content that looks like it is only placed for search engines, ... that will influence if the page is accepted for the index or that can cause  penalties)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO is which off-topic at Stack Overflow

Comment: @JohnConde: source for SEO being off-topic at Stack Overflow? Judging from a search on meta.stackoverflow.com, it depends on the question: see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10800/why-are-seo-questions-shut-down-as-not-programming-related/ This question sounds to me like it's asking about whether search engines can see content on a site that relies heavily on JavaScript. It's less SE-optimisation, more SE-being-able-to-see-my-sites-content-at-all. I say on-topic.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite 1. Click on the SEO tag and read the content. 2. There's a site dedicated to SEO and other webmaster-related stuff: [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: @JohnConde: Neither of those points explains why *this question* is off-topic. This is about making content delivered by a specific JavaScript pattern visible to search engines. It's not SEO.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the content to be indexed by search engines then you need to have a real URL for each page, and for the page to load the important content even if JavaScript is not available.

This will involve replicating your Backbone logic server-side.

Then, when you update the view with JS, use [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) to change the URL to the one which will generate the same view server side.

Note that the Google `#!` approach is a hack that predates the history API.

Comment: @sp00m — No. Don't use `#!`. It is a dirty hack. We have pushState now.